# How could I subtract a 1xN eigen matrix from a MxN matrix, like numpy does?

Tags: c++, eigen

I could not summarize a 1xN matrix from a MxN matrix like I do in numpy.

I create a matrix of `np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)` with eigen like this:

```
int buf[9];
for (int i{0}; i < 9; ++i) {
    buf[i] = i;
}
m = Map<MatrixXi>(buf, 3,3);
```

Then I compute mean along row direction:

```
    m2 = m.rowwise().mean();
```

I would like to broadcast `m2` to 3x3 matrix, and subtract it from `m`, how could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use appropriate types for your values, `MatrixXi` lacks the vector operations (such as broadcasting). You also seem to have the bad habit of declaring your variables well before you initialise them. Don't.

This should work

```
std::array<int, 9> buf;
std::iota(buf.begin(), buf.end(), 0);

auto m = Map<Matrix3i>(buf.data());
auto v = m.rowwise().mean();
auto result = m.colwise() - v;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no numpy-like broadcasting available in Eigen, what you can do is reuse the same pattern that you used:

```
m.colwise() -= m2
```

(See [Eigen tutorial on this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html))

N.B.: `m2` needs to be a vector, not a matrix. Also the more fixed the dimensions, the better the compiler can generate efficient code.

Comment: I do `m.rowwise() - m2`, but only got the error of ** static assertion failed: YOU_TRIED_CALLING_A_VECTOR_METHOD_ON_A_MATRIX EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_VECTOR_ONLY(OtherDerived)**.

Comment: It seems we cannot let one matrix minus another matrix, when they have different shapes.

Comment: Did you use `-=` or `-`?

Comment: I see no difference here actually.

Comment: I use 3.3.7, and the error message seems same to me.

Comment: @coincheung what is the type of `m2`? it can't be (an alias for) `Matrix<int, Dynamic, Dynamic>`, it has to be `Matrix<int, 1, /*N or Dynamic*/>`

Comment: @Caleth Indeed, that should solve this error message.

Answer (score 0):

While the `.colwise()` method already suggested should be preferred in this case, it is actually also possible to broadcast a vector to multiple columns using the [`replicate`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a60dadfe80b813d808e91e4521c722a8e) method.

```
m -= m2.replicate<1,3>();
// or
m -= m2.rowwise().replicate<3>();
```

If `3` is not known at compile time, you can write

```
m -= m2.rowwise().replicate(m.cols());
```